# How to set tiles dynamically in a tilemap?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a pre-created tile map with red tiles. I want to be able to go through my tilemap and if a tile is a red tile then set it to a blue tile.

I have the following idea

```
public Tile blue;
public Tile red;
```

I am not sure however how to loop through all tiles and then set the tile next to it to red if the tile is blue.

Can anyone give me any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nested loop like @live627 would work if you already have an existing tilemap. Would you always want to check after you create? Because you map them as red/blue the same time as you generate them. This will save you some computing time. However this only works on even grid.

Grid.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Grid : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int gridSize = 10;
    public Tile tilePrefab;

    void Start() {
        SetGrid();
    }

    public void SetGrid() {
        int total = gridSize * gridSize;

        for(int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            int posX = (int)Mathf.Floor(i/gridSize);
            int posY = i % gridSize;

            Tile t = Instantiate(tilePrefab).GetComponent<Tile>();
            t.SetPosition(posX, posY);

            if((posX + posY) % 2 == 0)
                t.SetColor(Color.blue);
            else
                t.SetColor(Color.red);
        }
    }
}
```

Tile.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Tile : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;

    private Renderer m_Renderer;


    private void Awake() {
        this.m_Renderer = this.GetComponent<Renderer>();
    }

    public void SetPosition(int x, int y) {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;

        this.transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
    }
    public void SetColor(Color c) {
        m_Renderer.material.color = c;
    }
}
```

This will create a grid that will generate a chess-like grid for you in a one-dimensional loop, instead of nested loop.

This particular loop:

```
int total = gridSize * gridSize;

        for(int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            int posX = (int)Mathf.Floor(i/gridSize);
            int posY = i % gridSize;

            Tile t = Instantiate(tilePrefab).GetComponent<Tile>();
            t.SetPosition(posX, posY);

            if((posX + posY) % 2 == 0)
                t.SetColor(Color.blue);
            else
                t.SetColor(Color.red);
        }
```

It can set you on track if you only want to loop through your list without nested loops. You will have to alter it to what you want to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a foreach loop. Check each tile. if it's red, set it to  blue.

If your tiles are stored in a 2d array, then the tile next to it should have an `x` value of the current tile + 1.

```
    for (int x = 0; x < gridSizeX; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < gridSizeY; y++)
             if (grid[x, y].color == Color.red)
                 grid[x + 1, y].color = Color.blue;
```